# Create signature in nodejs algorithm rsa-sha1 private_key.pem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, openssl, rsa, sha1

Can I create signature like code below in Nodejs?

```rb
 # Load PRIVATE key
    private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(Rails.root + ENV['EPAY_PRIVATE_KEY']))

    # Sign your data
    signMessage = private_key.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, message)

    # Base64 message
    baseMessage = Base64.encode64(signMessage.to_s)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do the same thing in Node.js, creating a signature is quite easy, for example:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./private-key.pem', 'utf8');

const message = "some message data";
const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA1');
sign.update(message);
sign.end();
const signature = sign.sign(privateKey);
console.log("Signature: ", signature.toString('base64'));
```

This creates a base64 encoded SHA1 signature of the message.

Comment: I try but I get `Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag. ` Are you missing anything? 
private-key.pem start with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- .... -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. When I download key from server it wrong format. I convert it by: `openssl rsa -in private.key -out private.key`